# How to extract strings out of a binary file with ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, binary, extract

i want to extract string out of a memory dump.
i'm using windows xp,ruby 1.9-mingw

the dump file is generated by a tool -- HiperDrop.exe

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: If you just want the strings, have you considered the `strings(1)` tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a good start:

```
str = IO.read('/path/to/file', :mode => 'rb')
printable_chars = %r{[A-Za-z0-9`~!@#%^&*()-_=+|'";:/?.>,< \t\$\{\}\[\]\\]{10,}}
str.scan(printable_chars).each do |match|
  puts match
end
```

Of course, change `'/path/to/file'` to the location of the memory dump.  You can also change the `10` at the end of the 2nd line to be some other minimum string length.

Answer (score 0):

I think sarnold above is right on the money. `strings` is a utility that's available in all *nix environments, and there are [free equivalents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) available from Microsoft for Windows. Just call the program from Ruby and parse the output as you please.